# How to generalize all object properties except some?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0

I want all properties to have a certain type, but I want the explicitly declared ones to override it:

```
interface Potato {
  a: number
  [all:string]: string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
type PotatoAll = { [all: string]: string };
type Potato = PotatoAll & { a: number };

let p = {} as Potato;

p['foo'] = 'foo';
p.a = 1;
p['a'] = 1;

p['foo'] = 1; //error
p['a'] = 'a'; //error
p.a = 'a'; //error
```